# Dymamic update data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here HTML code. I had created the table and used some ng modal

```html
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Website</th>
                <th>Edit data</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
                <td><span>{{ contact.name }}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{ contact.username }}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{ contact.email }}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{ contact.phone }}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{ contact.website }}</span></td>
                <td><button class="edit-data" (click)="openEdit(contentEdit, contact)">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<ng-template #contentEdit let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Edit data</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form [formGroup]="editForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input formControlName="name" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input formControlName="username" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input formControlName="email" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input formControlName="phone" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="website">Website</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input formControlName="website" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="border text_center">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info" (click)="updateContent()">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I'm trying to write function that will be automatically update data without backend. I think that it should be work with arrays (find some data by key and change it for a new input value). Can you help me to understand it? Which method should I use?

```typescript
    export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {
     
      contacts: Contact[] = [];
      editForm!: FormGroup;
      patchValue!: void;
      closeResult!: string;
      contact!: Contact;

      constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private modalService: NgbModal
      ) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.updateContact();
        this.contacts = [];
        this.getContacts();
        this.editForm = this.fb.group({
          name: [''],
          username: [''],
          email: [''],
          phone: [''],
          website: ['']
        });
      }

      getContacts() {
        this.httpClient.get<any>('some url').subscribe(
          response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.contacts = response;
            localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(this.contacts));
            localStorage.getItem('contact');
          }
        );
      }
      

      openEdit(targetModal:any, contact:Contact) {
        this.modalService.open(targetModal, {
          centered: true,
          backdrop: 'static',
          size: 'lg'
        });
        this.editForm.patchValue({
          name: contact.name,
          username: contact.username,
          email: contact.email,
          phone: contact.phone,
          website: contact.website
        });
      }

      updateContact(): any {
        ???? problem is here
       }
```

Comment: That is, I open a form, enter data into it, save it, and these changes are displayed on the screen. There is no need to send changes to the server.

Comment: Bro, I've been racking my brain for 10 hours, please just tell me what's wrong)

Comment: I added the view

Comment: updateContent must insert new data by clicking on SaveChanges button

Comment: Yes, you are right, I want to save changes to existing contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you do not have any immutable field (field which you are not allowing user to edit eg. contact id) you will have to store the index of contact whenever you select to update it because the user can change all the fields and you won't be able to tell which contact got updated.

e.g.
In HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts;let i = index">
    <td><span>{{ contact.name }}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{ contact.username }}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{ contact.email }}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{ contact.phone }}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{ contact.website }}</span></td>
    <td><button class="edit-data" (click)="openEdit(contentEdit, contact, i)">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

And update your modal function to take the index as argument as well so that it can save the currently selected contact.

```
openEdit(targetModal:any, contact:Contact, contactIndex: number) {
    this.selectedContactIndex = contactIndex;
    this.modalService.open(targetModal, {
      centered: true,
      backdrop: 'static',
      size: 'lg'
    });
    this.editForm.patchValue({
      name: contact.name,
      username: contact.username,
      email: contact.email,
      phone: contact.phone,
      website: contact.website
    });
  }
```

Then whenever you update your changes simply override the object at that index.

```
updateContact(): any {
    // Do your validations here
    const formValue = this.editForm.value;
    this.contacts[this.selectedContactIndex] = formValue;
}
```

PS: It would be better if can have some sort of field (eg. contactId) which the user can't change while editing the contact so as to make your job of saving the changes easier. That way you can simply use Array.find to get the respective object from array by using contact id and you won't have to save the index somewhere.

Comment: Another problem: after editing the code the table don't view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried backendless database platforms? Like firebase. I would suggest trying [angularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire)

It's as easy as,

```
updateContact(id: string, contact:Contact) {
  let doc = this.afs.collection('values', ref => ref.where('id', '==', id));
  doc.snapshotChanges().subscribe((res: any) => {
    let id = res[0].payload.doc.id;
    this.afs.collection('values').doc(id).update(contact);
  });
}
```

NOTE this should work if your id is unique and only returns one query result